# can i change JFrame on clicking the image in slideshow

Tags: java

for example , amazon have slides about offers and we click on any image.it direct us towards the respective page...what is logic behind that.
can anyone help..
as i created slideshow

package tryButton;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Slider extends JFrame{
    JLabel pic;
    Timer tm;
    int x = 0;
    //Images Path In Array
    String[] list = {
                      "/home/akshay/Documents/images/image1.jpeg",//0
                      "/home/akshay/Documents/images/image2.jpeg",//1
                      "/home/akshay/Documents/images/image3.jpg",//2
                      "/home/akshay/Documents/images/image4.jpg",//3
                      "/home/akshay/Documents/images/image5.jpg",//4
                      "/home/akshay/Documents/images/image6.png",//5
                      //"C:/Users/samsng/Desktop/jv7.jpg"//6
                    };

    public Slider(){
        //super("Java SlideShow");
        pic = new JLabel();
        pic.setBounds(40, 30, 700, 300);

        //Call The Function SetImageSize
        SetImageSize(5);
               //set a timer
        tm = new Timer(2000,new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SetImageSize(x);
                x += 1;
                if(x >= list.length )
                    x = 0; 
            }
        });
        add(pic);
        tm.start();
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(800, 400);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#bdb67b"));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    //create a function to resize the image 
    public void SetImageSize(int i){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(list[i]);
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon newImc = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        pic.setIcon(newImc);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    new Slider();
}
}
```

i want if i click on any image in slideshow it will direct me to certain page

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Is there an issue with the code that you've posted? Do you want to pass a URL to a browser when the user interacts with your Java application? Do you want to replicate the existing behavior in javascript?

Comment: using the code that i have posted,i created a slideshow of images in eclipse IDE.if i run that code i get output like images are sliding,now what i wanted to do that !.If i click on any image in slideshow then it will direct me to the particular page.so what can i do